# qt3d and the oculus sdk

Tags: qt, oculus, virtual-reality, qt3d

Given qt3d's structure, is it possible to integrate the oculus sdk with a qt3d application?
I have tried but my two main obstacles are:

1. I cant use the textures from the texture swap chain created by the oculus sdk as a render target attachment
2. I am not able to call ovr_SubmitFrame at the end of each frame since qt3d doesnt have a signal that would allow me to do so.

Has anyone successfully gotten the oculus sdk to work with qt3d? If so, how did you overcome these issues?

Are there any plans for allowing the integration of VR SDKs (not just oculus') in qt3d in further releases?

Answer (score 3):

You could probably do it with some sort of custom framegraph that encapsulated the stereo rendering functionality and included a custom component that could take the currently rendered content and submitted it to the SDK prior to the swapbuffer call.

Alternatively you could dive into the code that processes the framegraph itself and see how hard it would be to customize it to work against a VR API.  I've done significant work with integrating Qt apps with VR, but not specifically with Qt3D.

Answer (score 2):

The frame graph will indeed provide one part of the solution for the stereoscopic rendering setup. There is already an anaglyphic stereo example showing most of what you need that ships with Qt 3D.

To integrate the swap chain of the occulus SDK will require deeper integration. I do not know the details of the Occulus SDK as yet but we can take a look.

From what I can see you should be able to do something analogous to the Scene3D custom Qt Quick 2 item to be able to render to the textures provided by the Occulus SDK and to tell Qt 3D which OpenGL Context to use. See

http://code.qt.io/cgit/qt/qt3d.git/tree/src/quick3d/imports/scene3d?h=5.7

Nicolas, I also do not appreciate you publicly saying that KDAB are not much help. I only received an email from Karsten on Friday which I responded to despite being on vacation saying that we can help but it will be on a best efforts basis since you are not paying and I have a very full workload preparing Qt 3D for release at the end of the month along with Qt 5.7. Today is a public holiday in the UK, as you are aware, yet you are already saying detrimental things about us.

You were also directed to post to the interest@qt-project.org mailing list on the qt-forums as I do not tend to monitor SO or the qt-forums on a regular basis. You could have also emailed us directly or via the development@qt-interest mailing list.

We would be more than happy to set up a support agreement with you.

Comment: I apologize for that comment. I deleted it. The project i'm working on is open source and i'm pretty much a one-man shop so i wont be able to afford a support agreement. I have looked into the suggestions you have made and they were helpful, however i am still stuck. I will post the issue in the mailing list. Thank you.